# Function in SQL about compilation error

Tags: function, plsql, date-arithmetic

I'm new to the SQL, I want to create a function that return professors age by get the Pro_DOB.

HERE are my code.

```
Create or Replace FUNCTION pro_age
(Pro_DOB IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
current_age NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT Pro_DOB,Pno INTO current_age FROM(Select Pro_DOB,Pno FROM professors)
WHERE Pno =Pro_DOB; 
current_age:=Trunc((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('Pro_DOB', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))/365.25);
RETURN current_age;
END;
/
```

It show me compilation error after I create it.

And how can I execute it?

Comment: By the way, the Pro_DOB is already store in the script, I just want to retrieve it into this function. Thank You.

Comment: Don't use 365.25 to do your calculations - instead, you should be using `months_between`, and then dividing that by 12. Also, you have `to_date('Pro_DBO', ...)`... The string "Pro_DBO" is not a date and it's definitely not in MM/DD/YYYY format! Remove the single quotes from around it.

Comment: Also, why are you doing that select statement? Not only are you selecting two columns but only returning them into one (non-record/collection) variable (which will error), you're then not using any of the information. And what happens if there's more than one row that matches that select? You just need to calculate the age from the date of birth passed in, and today's date (sysdate). No need for anything else, right?

Comment: Today's tip: indent code to indicate the block dependency level. It makes the logic much easier to understand. Also, lowercase code is easier to read and looks more professional. Nobody codes any other language in uppercase (view the source of this page and tell me it'd be improved by uppercasing the keywords or whatever you're doing with `Create or Replace FUNCTION`).

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to create a function that return professors age by get the Pro_DOB"

Your implementation of the rules seems a little confused:

```
WHERE Pno =Pro_DOB
```

Is the real logic that you want to look up the Professor's Date Of Birth using their ID (`pno`) and then calculate their age?

If so, your function should look something like this:

```
create or replace function pro_age
    (p_id in professors.pno%type)
    return number
is
    current_age number;
begin
    select trunc(months_between(sysdate, pro_dob)/12)
    into current_age 
    from professors
    where pno = p_id; 
    return current_age;
end;
/
```

The date arithmetic uses the built-in function `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` to calculate the number of months between the DOB and the current date. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669) Dividing by 12 gives number of years and the `TRUNC()` ensures an integer, because age is generally expressed as whole years.

Note that the variables in the `INTO` clause need to match the columns in the query's projection (number and datatype).

> "how can I execute it?"

Functions return a value which we must assign to something. So you could run this anonymous PL/SQL block in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> var age number
SQL> accept professor_id prompt "please enter PNO for professor: " 
please enter PNO for professor: 123
SQL> begin
  2      :age := pro_age(&professor_id);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print age

       AGE
----------
        32

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively you could simply write a function which calculates the age from a passed Date Of Birth

```
create or replace function calc_age
    (p_dob in date)
    return number
is
begin
    return trunc(months_between(sysdate, p_dob)/12);
end;
/
```

This function you could include in a query like so:

```
select pno                           
       , pro_dob
       , calc_age(pro_dob) as pro_age
from professors
/
```